# How banking mobile applications keep data secure without Secure Element (SE)?

Tags: android, mobile

Most of the banking mobile applications get installed on nearly all smart phones such as Android based mobile devices.

But to be secure and to make cryptographic operations, I assume they need to keep some secret data in a secure storage such as Secure Element (SE).

But not every mobile phone has SE in it.

So, how does these banking mobile applications keep their secret data safe?

Comment: Every time you try to reply, you create a new account and post it as an answer. Please use the same account. If you do not, all of your answers will be deleted. You are not using this site as required.

Comment: If you do not want to register, then you are not ready to use this site.

Answer (score 3):

You must differenciate between Simple banking app where you can do some sort of account management and payment application.

**Banking App** rely on webservices so all security items relies only on how secure the communication is between the app and the server side and what authentication mechanism you are using(eg:two factor authentication)

**Payment App** Making Contactless Payment with your phone.

Android offers two possibilities:

1. Hardware Based Solution:
   hardware based rely on Secure elements currently there is three types of secure elements:

   - SIM Based
   - Embeded Secure Element
   - SD Card

As this implementation is hardware it can be considered as secure.

2. Software based solution:

Since Android 4.4, Android has introduced Host Card Emulation(HCE), to give the possiblity to emulate a plastic card and all contactless data exchange. android offers basic security, so another layer of security is mandated like whitebox cryptographie, Other features like device and user authentication.

Both solution rely on another mechanism which is called Tokenization, so the reel card holder data will never get used between the app and the terminals.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, banking mobile apps require you to enter a PIN to access anything more than the balance of a couple of accounts. Then if you want to add a new payee, you have to answer some security questions.

So without having decompiled a mobile banking app, to be sure, I would assume that the app has some authentication information encrypted using the PIN. 
So even if a bad person was able to get a copy of all of the data on disk belonging to the app, they would still need the PIN to use it. This is similar to the security level of your bank card. Better since you can't skim a phone, like you can with a bank card.

Even if a bad person got hold of your phone and PIN, they will need to know the answers to your security questions (which will be stored/processed) on the banks servers; to add themselves as a payee.

Furthermore the android (and iOS) operating system do not let one app access another app's private data. To share data between apps you need to save it to the shared area filesystem, or use one of the other approved APIs (e.g., copy paste)

What Secure Elements protect you from is a compromised operating system (which the other layers of trust are built upon. In the case of a banking app the risk of a bad person compromising the OS on your phone, to then record you entering your PIN, and copying the encrypted credentials, and guessing the security questions, is pretty darn low! Less than the risk of someone stealing your Bank card and PIN.